# How to add date picker dialoge in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datepicker

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    y = calendar?.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    m = calendar?.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    d = calendar?.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    var dialog = DatePickerDialog(applicationContext, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { picker, i, i2, i3 ->

    },y!!,m!!,d!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dialog.show()
It should look like this:

```kotlin
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

}, year, month, day)

datePickerDialog.show()
```